# NVDA reading dynamically-added content twice

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I'm working on making a dynamic web application accessible to the visually impaired via screen readers, and I'm running into an annoying problem. When I test my code (see below) with JAWS, it works perfectly fine. But when I use NVDA, I'm getting the dynamically-added content is being read TWICE by this reader in Firefox, and not being read at all in IE9.

Has anyone ever seen this kind of behavior before?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Mike's Alert Test Page</TITLE>       
</HEAD>
<BODY>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function simulateErrors()
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById("inlineErrors");  

                if (elem != null && elem != undefined) {
                    elem.innerHTML = '<DIV role="alert">I am some alert text.</DIV>';
                }
            }
    </script>       
    <H1>Test Page</H1>
    <DIV ID="inlineErrors"  role="none"></DIV>
    <DIV ID="buttons">
        <!--<BUTTON onClick="simulateErrors()" type="button">Simulate Errors</BUTTON>-->
        <input type="submit" value="Simulate Errors" onClick="simulateErrors()"/>
    </DIV>
</BODY>
```

Comment: None is an invalid value for the role attribute. I am not sure if that would do anything.

Comment: You should probably look into the aria-live attribute, along with aria-busy.

Answer (score 1):

Set `role="log"` and `aria-live="assertive"` to the `inlineErrors` div. Then simply insert other DIVs into that div for your errors and it should only be read out once.

Look at the `assertiveAnnounce` function in [this](https://github.com/dylanb/a11yfy) jQuery library  for code that works across many different browsers.